# SOLR - Can I get Parent fields and Child fields in the same result?

Tags: join, solr

I'm using SOLR 4.6 with Parent and Child documents.
I know that I can use 'join' or 'block join' to find documents of specific type (Child or Parent),

But, can I get Parent doc fields and Child doc fields in the same response?

For Example:
If I have **Person** with **firstName=Bob** and **LastName=Marley**
And Child doc **Address** with **City=NY**

I would like to get **firstName=Bob**, **LastName=Marley** and **City=NY** in the result document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Index time Block join with parent child relations and use the expand component (Solr 4.8) in the query. For more details check  Joel's post @ http://heliosearch.org/expand-block-join/

Comment: heliosearch.org is gone, so this answer isn't very useful anymore.  Is there any Solr documentation you can point to?

Answer (score 1):

According Solr Documentation it is not possible.  http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join

"For people who are used to SQL, it's important to note that Joins in Solr are not really equivalent to SQL Joins because no information about the table being joined "from" is carried forward into the final result. A more appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".

This Solr request...

/solr/collection1/select ? fl=xxx,yyy & q={!join from=inner_id to=outer_id}zzz:vvv
Is comparable to this SQL statement...

SELECT xxx, yyy
FROM collection1
WHERE outer_id IN (SELECT inner_id FROM collection1 where zzz = "vvv")

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is still impossible BUT. There is a patch that can be found [here - SOLR-5285](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5285)

Answer (score 0):

Child documents can be retrieved with the help of expand attribute as explained in [expand block join](http://heliosearch.org/expand-block-join/). If we add

```
expand=true&expand.q=*:*&expand.field=_root_
```

to the query. We should be able to get all child documents in "extended" attribute.